# How to assign button in TkInter to my script?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I'm new to python, and this site, and I have a question.

```
#App design below
import tkinter as tk

Height = 700
Width = 800

def test_function(entry):
    print("This is the entry:", entry)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=Height, width=Width)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Random Click!", font=40, command=lambda: test_function(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(lower_frame)
label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop
#Work below
import random
min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y" or roll_again == " y" or roll_again == "Yes" or roll_again == " yes" or roll_again == " Y":
    print ("Rolling the dices...")
    print ("The values are....")
    val_a = (random.randint(min, max))
    val_b = (random.randint(min, max))
    print(val_a)
    print(val_b)
    total = val_a + val_b
    print("The total amount added up is " + str(total))
    roll_again = input("Roll the dices again?")

while roll_again == "no" or roll_again == "n" or roll_again == " n" or roll_again == "No" or roll_again == " no" or roll_again == " N":
    coin_flip = input("Do you want to flip a coin then?")
    while coin_flip == "yes" or coin_flip == "Yes" or coin_flip == " yes" or coin_flip == " Yes" or coin_flip == "y" or coin_flip == "Y" or coin_flip == " y" or coin_flip == " Y":
        print("Flipping coin...")
        print("You got...")
        coinfliplist = ["Heads", "Tails"]
        print(random.choice(coinfliplist))
        coin_flip = input("Do you want to flip again?")
    while coin_flip == "no" or coin_flip == "n":
            exit()
```

I was watching a little video on how to make an app on python, and I followed it to a point, but now I need help because I don't get the video. I want to assign the button to execute everything below the `#work below` comment, and the entry to be used for typing in Y or N. Can someone help me as to how I would go about this? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest looking into creating multiple pages and creating buttons that function to go between pages. this way you understand how tkinder functions and is structured when you build your own application. Then work on this practice, you can check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBUpjijYtCk if you find video tutorials best but this isnt exactly the best tutorial

Comment: Be careful with the `input("Do you want to flip again")`. It will cause the GUI window to freeze whilst it is waiting for user input. You might want to look into putting it into another thread, but threading is a fairly advanced topic.

Comment: @Oli, I'll try to figure this threading stuff out and fix that issue, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @GrahamOrmond, I'll look at those tutorials and probably make a new file to test that out, thanks.

Comment: @Boinbo maybe look into pygame for creating your first GUI then move onto tkinder. This way you can learn functions along with it. It's also easier in my opinion to learn than tkinder and you'll get a fun little game out of it too.

Comment: @GrahamOrmond alright, will do!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to bring you 'root.mainloop()' to the bottom of the code. Note that you forgot to add the parentheses after root.mainloop(). Check your code please.

If you want your button to execute all that is below your comment, then you have to define that particular snippet within a function and then set the command of the button to that function. But you have to define the function before defining your button.
It should look something like this:

```
def arbitrary_function_name():
    #Put all the code below your comment in here. Don't forget to indent.

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Random Click!", font=40, command=arbitrary_function_name) #Remember, don't put the parentheses after the function name in the command.
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)
```

Try cleaning out your code a bit too. I tried running it and it crashed. If it runs for you then that's good.

Comment: The code I wrote runs for me, but I'll see what I can do to clean it out. Thank you for the answer too, I'll try it out in my code.

Comment: Edit here because it won't let me edit the previous comment, @Waris0010, how would I get the output to show up in the label, and for it to let me type my responses in the entry section?

Comment: @Boinbo Waris is correct that you need parentheses after `root.mainloop`, because `root.mainloop` is just a value that represents the `root.mainloop` function, and doesn't actually do anything, whereas `root.mainloop()` calls the function. This causes the code after the `root.mainloop()` to not be run until after your app window is closed, but the GUI will not work properly unless you call `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: @Boinbo I would recommend creating a new question for getting output in a label and input from an entry. If you link it here I would be happy to answer it if someone else doesn't get there first!

Answer (score 0):

if I'm getting you intentions correctly then this should help:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()

roll_again = ""

def workCallBack(choice):
   roll_again = choice

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Random Click!", font=40, command= lambda: workCallBack(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

root.mainloop() # should be at the bottom
```

since you are new to python it's fine, but I strongly recommend tidy up you code with some functions to reduce duplicated code, etc..

Comment: I'm not completely sure how functions work to be honest, which is why I didn't use them a lot, but thanks for the answer nonetheless!